# SP - How to get Picture libraries in my current site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development

I want to get all Picture libraries in my current web.

**This is my code:**

```
foreach (SPPictureLibrary picLib in oWeb.Folders)
{
  if (picLib.Name.Contains("Picture"))
  {
   _ddLibraryName.Items.Add(picLib.Title);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To get all Picture libraries, Try to check all list based on its `BaseTemplate = PictureLibrary`

```
   foreach(var list in oWeb.Lists){
        if(list.BaseTemplate.Equals(SPListTemplateType.PictureLibrary))
        {
         // do your code like add to drop down list or or array
         _ddLibraryName.Items.Add(list.Title);
         }
    }
```